# BBB Mark/Space parity

Tags: linux, serial-port, embedded-linux, beagleboneblack, uart

So I've enable UART-1 on the BBB. I've tried setting it up to use mark/space parity via termios & stty. According to the [doc](http://phytec.com/wiki/images/7/72/AM335x_techincal_reference_manual.pdf) it supports this.

**termios setup:**

```
options.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;      
options.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;         
options.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;        

options.c_cflag |= CS8;
options.c_cflag &= ~PARODD;
options.c_cflag |= PARENB;
options.c_cflag |= CMSPAR;

options.c_oflag = 0;
options.c_lflag = 0;
options.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY | IGNBRK);
options.c_iflag |= INPCK | PARMRK;
```

**stty output:**

```
speed 9600 baud; rows 0; columns 0; line = 48;
intr = }; quit = ^A; erase = <undef>; kill = ^P; eof = M-4; eol = M-`; eol2 = <undef>; swtch = M-^X;
start = E; stop = M-p; susp = M-6; rprnt = $; werase = M-6; lnext = 8; flush = M-^Y;
min = 182; time = 174;
parenb -parodd cmspar cs8 -hupcl -cstopb -cread clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar parmrk inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl -ixon -ixoff iuclc -ixany -imaxbel
-iutf8
-opost -olcuc -ocrnl -onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
-isig -icanon -iexten -echo -echoe -echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt -echoctl -echoke
```

**test:**

```
echo -e "\x30\x31\x30" > /dev/ttyO1
```

**expected results:**

```
000110000 000110001 000110000
```

**actual results:**

```
000110000 100110001 000110000
```

I can't seem to figure out where I'm going wrong. Like I said, the docs seem to say that it should work, and I know if I go into the kernel and hack omap-serial I can make it use mark/space parity. I don't want to maintain a hacked kernel for something so trivial though.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: *"I've tried setting it up to use mark/space parity"* -- Mark and space are two different states.  You can only choose one parity configuration.  What is it?  Your *"results"* are meaningless because you haven't described the actual serial configurations of both ends.  *"Like I said, the docs seem to say that it should work"* -- Did you study the *termios* **man** page?  Did you satisfy the **_BSD_SOURCE** or **_SVID_SOURCE** requirement?  BTW that's low-quality code for configuring *termios*.  See http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/libc/libc_12.html#SEC237

Comment: First off, by mark/space I simply meant stick, or cmspar. Second, I clearly give my settings and expected results... Both clearly illustrate space parity. Third, there is no secondary device I'm using a logic analyzer so ..yeah. Fourth, its example code to illustrate the issue and ask if I had missed a config mask somewhere.  Thank you for your time, but your comment is quite useless as you really didnt address either if its possible on the hardware, or any mistakes I may have made from a termios standpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Never found out why the STICK parity wasn't working from userspace, so instead of mucking about with the termios hacks to try to support a 9bit UART, I simply jumped over to the PRU and everything's running smooth. Using STICK parity without issue.